# CSS3 fadeout effect on hover

Tags: css, css-transitions

Wanna make a small move and fadeout effect using CSS3 transitions, but when I apply more than one property to `-webkit-transition-property` it does not work like it suppose to do.

here is what I've already done: http://jsfiddle.net/riless/48P7Q/

Comment: Odd, works great in Firefox, but acts weird in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 transition:all .3s linear;
```

and related browser prefixes to id #box.

You are unable to have two CSS properties attached to a transition, but you can attach the property "all" which would effect all css properties.

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/48P7Q/2/

Here's the full HTML and CSS

HTML:

```
<span id="box">bubble</span>
```

CSS:

```
#box{ 
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    border-radius:3px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 #000;
    -webkit-transition:all .3s linear;
    -moz-transition:all .3s linear;
    -o-transition:all .3s linear;
    transition:all .3s linear;
}

#box:hover{
    opacity:0; bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: still having the same weird behaviour in chrome!

Comment: I slowed down the transition duration, and it seems to be working for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/48P7Q/3/

Comment: you are not on chrome ?

Comment: I'm using chrome Version 30.0.1599.101

Comment: works well on firefox two, but not on Chrome 29.0.1547.65 under Ubuntu

Comment: Can you link me the JSFiddle that you are working with currently? Or are you looking at mine?

Comment: You can specify more than one property to transition in the CSS spec. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/ If all other parts of the transition are the same, though, it might be easier to define the various transition properties individually than to use the `transition` shorthand that combines them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `-webkit-` prefix.

I think the prefixed version is outdated and dont work the same as the non prefixed one, so:

```
transition: all 0.3s linear;
```

and

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
```

don't gives the same result.

Here is the version of the code that works: http://jsfiddle.net/riless/48P7Q/10/